# Select Second Image Not In <noscript> Tag

Tags: html, css, selector

Wordpress is returning the  followed by a  tag and the same  inside. In my case, I have two images and I need to select the second  and ignore the  ones.

Here is a simple example of the HTML:

```
<div>
 <img>
 <noscript>
  <img>
 </noscript>
 <img> <!-- Select this <img> -->
  <noscript>
   <img>
  </noscript>
 </div>
```

Here is the CSS I have at the moment.

```
div img:nth-child(2){
 // style goes here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`:nth-child()` selects elements that are the `n`<sup>th</sup> children of their own parents. However, the second child of that `<div>` is the `<noscript>` element, so it won't select the `<img>`.

To select the `<img>`s that are the second `<img>` of their parent, you can use `:nth-of-type()` instead:

```
div img:nth-of-type(2){ ... }
```

Note that it will also select the second images inside the `<noscript>`s if they contain more than one `<img>`.

Answer (score 0):

Not a pro here but looks like you whant to chose one img from 2 available.

I think that the problem is that both images are child of `<div>`.

Try adding some attributes to `<img`> that you want to choose like `<img id='One' class='One'>` after that alter css to something like `img.One{//style goes here; }`

Comment: Of course, this method is possible if you have control of the output of the code, which is not always the case in frameworks like Wordpress. For example, if the piece of code is generated by a plugin or part of a theme and you don't want to hack it at the code level.